# Using jQuery to save the name of each div that has a specific class to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to loop through a list of divs. If a div in that list has the class name of "active", than I need to save the contents of the `<p></p>` tag of the specific div to a variable. I then need to place the contents of that variable in a the value of a hidden input element on a form. For example, here is some example HTML:

```
<div class="names">
  <div class="one active">
    <p>A</p>
  </div>
  <div class="two active">
    <p>B</p>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <p>C</p>
  </div>
  <div class="four active">
    <p>D</p>
  </div>
  <div class="five">
    <p>E</p>
  </div>
  <div class="six active">
    <p>F</p>
  </div>
</div>

<form action="form.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="list" id="list" value="">
</form>
```

Since four of the divs contain the "active" class, I need to save the content that is in each paragraph tag to a variable to be inserted into the value of the hidden field. In this example, the value of the field would be A, B, D, F.

I thought about doing something like this:

```
var userSelection = function() {
    $('.names div').each(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            return $(this).text();
        }
    });
};

$('#list').val(userSelection);
```

First off, that code doesn't work and I am also not even sure if that's the best way to go about solving my problem. Second, if anyone has a better idea of how to accomplish what I need, I would love to hear it.

Comment: It makes me sad when people don't create fiddles

Comment: `$('#list').val(userSelection());` You forgot execute the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `map()` to get an array of the text:

```
var textArr = $('.names div.active').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

From there, you could use `join()` to get a string you could write to the DOM:

```
var textString = textArr.join(', ');
```

Full, compressed code:

```
var userSelection = function() {
    return $('.names div.active').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(', ');
};

$('#list').val(userSelection());
```

Comment: what is get()? convert array to string?

Comment: @Dvir `map()` returns a jquery object. `get()` returns an actual array with the contents of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to Jason P's answer is to modify what you've got to return an array of the results, as you're calling a function into a variable that has multiple results:

```
var userSelection = function() {
    var output = [];
    $('.names div').each(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            output.push( $(this).text().trim() );
        }
    });
    return output;
};
```

[See JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz5uG/)

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle: http://jsbin.com/uQEJIkU/3/edit

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  values = []  
  $("div.active > p").each( function() {  
    values.push($(this).text())    
  })    
})
```